# How to store PySpark struct column in json

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, struct

I have a following column in spark dataframe:

```
TransactionList:map
  key:string
  value:struct
    type_id:integer
    epoch_utc:long
    source_type:string
    numbers:array
```

What would be a proper way to store this in json files, so later it can be easily loaded using Python json.load method?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't use `df.write.json` because it does not generate valid json files. Since you want to read the file with `json.load` I also assume that the file can hold inside the memory of the driver. In that case, you can do use `toJSON` and add what's missing to generate a valid json file:

```py
# sample data matching your schema
df = spark.range(10).withColumn("value", f.struct(
    f.lit(1).alias("type_id"),
    f.col("id").alias("epoch_utc"),
    f.lit("x").alias("source_type"),
    f.array(f.lit(1), f.lit(2)).alias("numbers"))
).select(f.create_map(f.lit("z"), f.col("value")).alias("TransactionList"))

# This generates a valid json file
f = open('output.json', 'w')
f.write('[' + df.toJSON().reduce(lambda a, b : a + ',' + b) + ']')
f.close()
```